# Is it possible to define patterns of composition in functions or functors?

Tags: haskell, composition

Consider the following situation. I define a function to process a list of elements by the typical way of doing an operation on the head and recalling the function over the rest of the list. But under certain condition of the element (being negative, being a special character, ...) I change sign on the rest of the list before continuing. Like this:

```
f [] = []
f (x : xs) 
    | x >= 0      = g x : f xs
    | otherwise   = h x : f (opposite xs)

opposite [] = []
opposite (y : ys) = negate y : opposite ys
```

As `opposite (opposite xs) = xs`, I become to the situation of redundant opposite operations, accumulating `opposite . opposite . opposite ...`.

It happens with other operations instead of `opposite`, any such that the composition with itself is the identity, like `reverse`.

Is it possible to overcome this situation using functors / monads / applicatives / arrows? (I don't understand well those concepts). What I would like is to be able of defining a property, or a composition pattern, like this:

```
opposite . opposite  = id    -- or, opposite (opposite y) = y
```

in order that the compiler or interpreter avoids to calculate the opposite of the opposite  (it is possible and simple (native) in some concatenative languages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this without any monads, since the logic is quite simple:

```
f g h = go False where 
  go _ [] = [] 
  go b (x':xs)
    | x >= 0    = g x : go b xs 
    | otherwise = h x : go (not b) xs
      where x = (if b then negate else id) x'
```

The body of the `go` function is almost identical to that of your original `f` function. The only difference is that `go` decides whether the element should be negated or not based on the boolean value passed to it from previous calls.

Comment: Sounds like `mapAccumL`.

Comment: @user3237465 ...and `mapAccumL` is `mapM` for the `State` monad. And, pow! We're back at monads. Only question is what level you're abstracting at. "Without monads" might be a good thing, or it might not -- depends a lot on what your goals are.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, I thought that a version with `mapAccumL` would be simpler, but I was [wrong](http://ideone.com/TmGEx5). The monadic version is more descriptive.

Comment: "Without monads" just meant without the Haskell Monad abstraction. Logically speaking, the `go` function could be written with the type `[a] -> Reader Bool [a]`. The logic of the two functions would be the same. The point of this answer, mainly, was to show that the desired semantics could be achieved with minimal modification to the original code.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, just keep a bit of state telling whether to apply `negate` to the current element or not. Thus:

```
f = mapM $ \x_ -> do
    x <- gets (\b -> if b then x_ else negate x_)
    if x >= 0
        then return (g x)
        else modify not >> return (h x)
```